# Random output from array 1 output instead of 2

Tags: javascript

I want to output 2 different random array objects.
This is what I got so far. But It only shows 1 output instead of 2. How is this possible?
I want to output 2 different random array objects.
This is what I got so far. But It only shows 1 output instead of 2. How is this possible?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<script>


  
  var myArray = [
  "Apples",
  "Bananas",
  "Pears"
];

    
var randomItem1 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
var randomItem2 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];


document.getElementById("randomItem1").innerHTML=randomItem1;
document.getElementById("randomItem2").innerHTML=randomItem2;

  

</script>


<div id = "randomItem1"> </div>
<div id = "randomItem2"> </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As the other answerer got it right now, and were first to answer, may I suggest you change mine to an upvote and accept the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, the only problem is you are overwriting to your document body, instead of two different divs.

You are also executing javascript before html, so it searches for elements that are not loaded. Putting javascript after the html solves that problem.

Do it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>



<div id = "randomItem1"> </div>
<div id = "randomItem2"> </div>

</body>
<script>



    var myArray = [
    "Apples",
    "Bananas",
    "Pears"
  ];


  var randomItem1 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomItem2 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];


  document.getElementById("randomItem1").innerHTML=randomItem1;
  document.getElementById("randomItem2").innerHTML=randomItem2;



</script>
</html>
```

For testing, you can add `console.log(randomItem1)` and `console.log(randomItem2)` between the lines.

Comment: Thanks for your respond, I got this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.

Comment: This is strange, I tried it now, and it works, are you sure that you are not making a typo with ids.

Comment: I've edited my question's snippets you can also see the error in there

Comment: Okey, Fixed it. Always put your <script> at the end of the  </body> . So either as last block before the </body> or between </body> and </html>. Your scripts should execute after html is loaded, so that your document.getElementById can actually find the elements :D

Comment: @atayenel Add that to your answer, where it belongs.

Comment: @LGSon I did, to the code, 1 hour ago. Is there a mistake ?

Comment: @atayenel No, but you should also add it as an explanation, as for some users it might not be obvious how the script is positioned.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things that goes one, and wrong:

1. the `document.body.innerHTML = randomItem1;` will overwrite the existing elements
2. when update to e.g. `document.getElementById("randomItem1").innerHTML = randomItem1;`, the `<script>` block needs to be positioned *after* the elements, or else they won't be found not being parse and loaded in the DOM.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<div id = "randomItem1"> </div>
<div id = "randomItem2"> </div>

<script>
  var myArray = [
    "Apples",
    "Bananas",
    "Pears"
  ];

  var randomItem1 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomItem2 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

  document.getElementById("randomItem1").innerHTML = randomItem1;
  document.getElementById("randomItem2").innerHTML = randomItem2;
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

---

An alternative is to use an event listener that will fire when the DOM is ready.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<script>
  var myArray = [
    "Apples",
    "Bananas",
    "Pears"
  ];

  var randomItem1 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomItem2 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    document.getElementById("randomItem1").innerHTML = randomItem1;
    document.getElementById("randomItem2").innerHTML = randomItem2;

  });
</script>

<div id = "randomItem1"> </div>
<div id = "randomItem2"> </div>

</body>

</html>
```